# PHP Array Get values. DigitalOcean list files and folders

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I'm using this to list all files and folders from a Digital Ocean space

//List all files and folders

`$myFiles = $space->ListObjects();`

When I echo the result

`echo '<pre>'; print_r($myFiles); echo '</pre>';`

I get this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Key] => dam/
            [LastModified] => 1589401286
            [ETag] => "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
            [Size] => 0
            [StorageClass] => STANDARD
            [Owner] => Array
                (
                    [DisplayName] => 7401583
                    [ID] => 7401583
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Key] => dam/detail-amethyst.jpg
            [LastModified] => 1589769638
            [ETag] => "4e62b16899ba8abfeffe611a8f945781"
            [Size] => 558352
            [StorageClass] => STANDARD
            [Owner] => Array
                (
                    [DisplayName] => 7401583
                    [ID] => 7401583
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
```

And so on.

I have tried

```
foreach ($myFiles as $key => $val) {
    echo $key;
}
```

But this just gives me 01234567....

How do I get the [Key] values? I would love to create an array with just the [Key] values in. For example [dam/,dam/detail-amethyst.jpg,,,,]

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `$keys = array_column($myFiles, 'Key');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here `echo $key;` is printing the Array's index values.

Do it like this:

```php
foreach ($myFiles as $key => $val) {
    echo $val['Key'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm surprised that I did not try that, I feel like I tried 1000 different ways :)